# Datatable not rendering in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to create a datatable in shiny. This solution has been working previously but I must have altered something for it to not anymore:

```
output$ltl_tbl <- renderDataTable({
  input$refresh
  ltl_view <- car()
  colnames(ltl_view) <- c('Carrier', 'Volume', 'CWT', 'On Time')
  DT::datatable(ltl_view, 
                options = list(lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50), 
                               pageLength = 10, 
                               orderClasses = TRUE, 
                               fillContainer = TRUE, 
                               searching = FALSE),
                rownames = FALSE 
  ) %>%
    formatCurrency(3, '$') %>% formatPercentage(4, 0) %>% formatCurrency(2, '', digits= 0)
})
```

I am just calling a dataframe from a reactive function, changing the column names, then creating the datatable with some options but this is not working and I cannot figure out why.

When I remove the column format (formatCurrency & formatPercentage) and also remove the lines above the actual datatable (e.g., changing column names and dataframe assignment), it will render the datatable in my shinyapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I must have added another package that made the call ambiguous. By adding the following in the user interface and server side, it worked.

```
DT::renderDataTable

DT::dataTableOutput
```